# WordPress - PHP list of PDF files

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written this code:

```
function userfunc_get_file_links($sub_folder) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $directory = get_stylesheet_directory()."/files/".$sub_folder;
        $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
        echo "<ul class='support_links'>";
        foreach ($scanned_directory as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li><a href='files/".$value."'>".$value."</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

I've added it to my functions file, and I can successfully apply it with a page template and it displays a list of file links.

(Template file):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: supportpage
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="inner-page">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="brack-cum">
                <div class="inner-small">
                <?php 
                   if (function_exists('wp_bac_breadcrumb')) {wp_bac_breadcrumb();}
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <div class="inner-small">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-page inner-small">
                <?php
                    the_content(); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php get_footer(); }?>
```

However, when I click them it brings up a 404 error and I can't work out why. I've tried resetting my permalinks and checking the FTP path (its 100% correct).

If I try moving my /files/ folder to the root directory of the server with

```
$directory = home_url()."/htdocs/files".$sub_folder;
```

It returns

> Warning: scandir(http://localhost/wordpress/files/application_notes):
>   failed to open dir: not implemented in
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen-child\user_functions.php
>   on line 5

The files are pdf files for the most part ("how_to_do_stuff.pdf" etc).

Any ideas on the steps I could take from here?

EDIT1: With the original code displaying the links but returning a WordPress 404 on click:

var_dump($directory)

```
string(93) "C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/files/application_notes"
```

var_dump($scanned_directory)

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(9) "test1.pdf"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "test2.pdf"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "test3.pdf"
}
```

With the code that produces the warning:

var_dump($directory)

```
string(57) "http://localhost/wordpress/htdocs/files/application_notes"
```

var_dump($scanned_directory)

```
NULL
```

Comment: Dump $directory and $scanned_directory,what do you get?

Comment: @Mihai Edited to show

Comment: That directory look strange to me uses \ for windows than switches to / for linux

Comment: You're mixing up URLs and File paths...

Comment: I thought it would indeed be the URI via WordPresses function to get the filepath "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()" to link to my files, but I'm not sure. Same warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close...but you need to output URLs if you want people to be able to click on the links:

```
function userfunc_get_file_links($sub_folder) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $directory = get_stylesheet_directory()."/files/".$sub_folder;
        $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
        echo "<ul class='support_links'>";
        foreach ($scanned_directory as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li><a href='".get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/files/" . $sub_folder . "/" . $value . "'>".$value."</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Here's what each part should do:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
// http://example.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme

'/files/' . $sub_folder . '/' . $value
// /files/subfolder/filename.txt
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so obvious!! Thanks a lot, much appreciated.